# C program that splits string into tokens and counts vowels

Tags: c, string, algorithm, count, strtok

I am trying to do a C program that splits string into tokens and counts vowels in each word found; if there are more than 2 vowels, show the word.
That's what I tried to do. I think strtok is the easiest way to get the words, but i cannot find the vowels and print the words. This program won't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s[100], *r;
    int i, contor,c;

    printf("s = ");
    gets(s);

    r = strtok(s, " ");

    while (r != NULL) 
    {

        while(*r!='\0')
        {
            if (*r == 'a' || *r == 'A' || *r == 'e' || 
                *r == 'E' || *r == 'i' || *r == 'I' || 
                *r =='o' || *r=='O' || *r == 'u' || *r == 'U')
            {
                contor++;
            }

            r++;
        }

        if (contor>=2)
            printf("%s \n",r);

        r = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never, never, never use `gets`. It is so prone to buffer overrun and so insecure it has been removed from the C11 library. Use `fgets` instead (or POSIX `getline`)

Answer (score 0):

yeah, because `r` points to nul-termination char already (because of your vowel search loop) when you call `printf`

You have to store the pointer to be able to print the word

```
const char *w = r;
while(*r!='\0')
{
    if (*r == 'a' || *r == 'A' || *r == 'e' || *r == 'E' || 
        *r == 'i' || *r == 'I' || *r =='o' || *r=='O' || 
        *r == 'u' || *r == 'U')
    {
        contor++;
    }

    r++;
}

if (contor>=2)
    printf("%s \n",w);
```

note that your `if` is highly inefficient. Converting to lowercase and/or using a `switch`/`case` statement would reduce complexity.

```
while(*r!='\0'){
    switch (tolower(*r))
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
           contor++;
    }
     r++;
}
```

Oh and *don't ever use `gets`*. It's been removed from the standard because it's unsafe. You can use `scanf` with a limit:

```
 scanf("%99s",s);
```

Comment: For an optimized, branchless isvowel, you can use `int isvowel(int c){unsigned x = (c|32)-'a';return ((x<32)<<(x&31)) & 1065233;}`

Comment: ... assuming an ASCII based system